# Set default print paper size when printing a pdf generated from crystal reports?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports, printing, pdf-generation

I am using crystal reports (the version that comes with visual studio 2008) to generate a pdf in an asp.net which then gets pulled into a client's browser.

Some of these reports are on legal size paper.  This means that for these reports our clients have to manually change the paper size in the print dialog every time they print.  Of course frequently they don't do this until they've already printed a 10 page report on the wrong paper thereby wasting time and paper.

Is there a way for me to embed information on the default paper size for printing inside the pdf?  I don't see an option for it on the crystal reports API, but I'm also not particularly familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default paper size is actually set in Crystal using File -> Page Setup; this will determine the output size of the PDF.  The thing you need to change is, unfortunately, on the client machines...in the print dialog of Adobe Acrobat, the "choose paper source by PDF page size" check box needs to be checked.  I believe this checkbox "sticks" across all printers and all documents once chosen.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's not the best option but that's a lot better than nothing.